# Cassandra wide row and simple row behind the scenes

Tags: cassandra

Trying to learn how cassandra works here, was very hard to get insights about how data is stored behind the scenes, hence im not sure i got it right and wanted to get corrected if i got it wrong, so far i understand that a typical row that the partition key (leftmost column or compuond column in the primary key) is unique, a row would be written to disk in a chunk that looks like this :

[image]

where the columns are sorted by their names.

But, if the partition key is not unique for then it would be considered a "wide row" and a row would look like the following examples :

[image]

Please correct me if i got it wrong...

Answer (score 2):

For Second part where you have compound primary key the structure will be somthing similar to first except for the fact that:

ColumnName will be replaced by `usrname1.comments|username1.comments_ts|username2.comments|username2.comments_ts`

> **VideoId** : usrname1.comments|username1.comments_ts|username2.comments|username2.comments_ts

Same thing will be true for comments_by_user

> **username**: videoid1.comments|videoid1.comments_ts|videoid2.comments|videoid2.comments_ts

PS: I am not good at drawing images so you have to do with this text answer.

For more details [Refer Slide 48](http://www.slideshare.net/DataStax/understanding-how-cql3-maps-to-cassandras-internal-data-structure/48?src=clipshare)